# Export Pinned Tabs from Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I have very many **pinned tabs** in Safari on the Mac. Is there a quick way to "export" them to another machine? (perhaps they can be synced via iCloud?)

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?  I would like to move my pinned tabs over to a new machine in one fell swoop without involving iCloud.  I am not permitted to use a disk restore or Time Machine backup so I need a manual solution.

Comment: There may be a solution for Firefox, which is useful to me as well.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1071320

Answer (score 2):

Its late but here's how you could do it:

- Go to Finder > (option + click Go in menu bar) Library > Safari
- Look for a file named 'LastSession.plist'
- Copy this over to the same location on your new machine (either via a USB or through the cloud)

(Quit, if needed and) Open Safari - your tabs should be right there!